# how to update data using put request in express js,mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

This is form and displays single data in this.
**singlepassword.js**

```
<html>
   <%- include("./partials/head.ejs") %>
    <body>
        <%- include("./partials/nav.ejs") %>
        <div class="container" style="height:379px;">
            <div class="row m-3">  
             <form class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" method="POST" action="/details">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-sm-9 text-info mt-2 mb-2">View Single data</h3>
                    <span class="col-sm-3 btn-group">
                        <a  role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-doc="<%= selection._id%>">Update</a>
                        <a  role="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-doc="<%= selection._id%>">Delete</a>
                        <a  role="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/details">Cancel</a> 
                    </span>  
                </div>    
                <input type="hidden" value="<%= selection._id%>"/>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="form-label text-light" for="website">Website</label><input class="form-control text-dark" id="website" type="text" name="website" value="<%= selection.website %>" required></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="form-label text-light" for="username">User Name</label><input class="form-control text-dark" id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<%= selection.username %>"  required></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="form-label text-light" for="pass">Password</label><input class="form-control text-dark" id="pass" type="password" name="password" value="<%= selection.password %>" required></div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%- include("./partials/footer.ejs") %>
<script>
    const trashcan = document.querySelector('a.delete');
    trashcan.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const endpoint = `/details/${trashcan.dataset.doc}`;
      fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'DELETE',
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => window.location.href = data.redirect)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the routing file and put request includes in this file.

**passwordRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const Password = require('../models/passwordList');
const router = express.Router();

//update data
router.put((req,res)=>{
  const id = req.params.id;
  
   Password.findByIdAndUpdate(id)
    .then((result) =>{
       console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
})

module.exports = router ;
```

this file includes mongoose schemas.

**passwordList.js**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const passwordSchema = new Schema({
    website:{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }

}, {timestamps: true});

const PasswordList = mongoose.model('PasswordList', passwordSchema);

module.exports = PasswordList;
```

How do update data when clicking the update button using put request?
After update data , should redirect details.js page

Comment: This may help you https://shockoe.com/ideas/development/node-js-storing-data-with-mongodb/

Comment: Thank you.But I am working with mongodb collection URL without locally installed.

Comment: I use this code instead of above passwordRoutes.js code.Data did not updated and  data restored again as new data.Why? const password_update = (req,res,next)=>{
  const id = req.params.id;

  let updatedData = {
    username:req.body.username,
    website:req.body.website,
    password:req.body.password
  }
  
   Password.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: updatedData})
    .then((result) =>{
       res.redirect('/details');
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
}